I get design time error: Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'LeaguesDbContext'
The error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'LeaguesDbContext'. The exception 'An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation.ForeignKeyPropertiesMappedToUnrelatedTables': The foreign key {'LeagueId'} on the entity type 'SoccerDivisionEntity' targeting 'SoccerContestLeagueEntity' cannot be represented in the database. Either the properties {'LeagueId'} aren't mapped to table 'Divisions', or the principal properties {'Id'} aren't mapped to table 'ContestLeagues'. All foreign key properties must map to the table to which the dependent type is mapped, and all principal properties must map to a single table to which the principal type is mapped. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.ForeignKeyPropertiesMappedToUnrelatedTables' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

My LeaguesDbContext:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerContest>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerContestLeague>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerContestCup>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerMatchDay>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerTeamMatch>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerMatchLeague>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SoccerPlayer>();

    // Relationships for Leagues
    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerAssociationEntity>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Leagues)
        .WithOne(l => l.Association)
        .HasForeignKey(l => l.AssociationId);

    // Relationships for Cups
    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerAssociationEntity>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Cups)
        .WithOne(c => c.Association)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.AssociationId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerDivisionEntity>()
        .HasMany(d => d.MatchDays)
        .WithOne(md => md.Division)
        .HasForeignKey(md => md.DivisionId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerDivisionEntity>()
        .HasOne(d => d.League)
        .WithMany(l => l.Divisions)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.LeagueId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(l => l.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerPlayerEntity>()
        .Ignore(p => p.PositionRatings);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerTeamMatchEntity>()
        .Ignore(t => t.StartingLineup)
        .Ignore(t => t.Substitutes); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerRoundEntity>()
        .HasOne(r => r.Cup)
        .WithMany(c => c.Rounds)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.CupId);

    // Ensure the tables are correctly mapped
    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerDivisionEntity>().ToTable("Divisions");
    modelBuilder.Entity<SoccerContestLeagueEntity>().ToTable("ContestLeagues");
}

[Table("Divisions")]
public class SoccerDivisionEntity : SoccerDivision
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [ForeignKey("LeagueId")]
    public SoccerContestLeagueEntity League { get; set; }
    public Guid LeagueId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(125)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Level { get; set; } // Lower numbers indicate higher tiers

    public virtual ICollection<SoccerMatchDayEntity> MatchDays { get; set; } = new List<SoccerMatchDayEntity>();

    [InverseProperty("Division")]  
    public virtual ICollection<SoccerTeamEntity> Teams { get; set; } = new List<SoccerTeamEntity>();

    public virtual List<SoccerTeamSeasonStatsEntity> Standings { get; set; } = new List<SoccerTeamSeasonStatsEntity>();
}

[Table("ContestLeagues")]  
public class SoccerContestLeagueEntity : SoccerContestLeague
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssociationId")]
    public SoccerAssociationEntity Association { get; set; }
    public Guid AssociationId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("League")]
    public ICollection<SoccerDivisionEntity> Divisions { get; set; } = new List<SoccerDivisionEntity>();

    [ForeignKey("ChampionTeamId")]
    public SoccerTeamEntity Champion { get; set; }
}

public class SoccerContestLeague : SoccerContest
{
        public virtual List<SoccerDivision> Divisions { get; set; } = new List<SoccerDivision>();

    public Guid? ChampionTeamId { get; private set; } // Nullable foreign key for champion team
    public SoccerTeam Champion { get; private set; }

    // Protected constructor for EF Core
    protected SoccerContestLeague() { }

//...
}

What is wrong?
I was trying Dropping the DB in design time using PowerShell.

Share also League entity class.

I added to the original post/question.
public class SoccerContestLeague : SoccerContest
{
public virtual List Divisions { get; set; } = new List();
public Guid? ChampionTeamId { get; private set; } // Nullable foreign key for champion team
public SoccerTeam Champion { get; private set; }

// Protected constructor for EF Core
protected SoccerContestLeague() { }

//...
}
